# Continuously redirect Git progress to QTextBrowser

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I would like to send git progress to a QTextBrowser in a QDialog so that I can give user feedback when I'm pulling repos. Ideally, it would be able to be multithreaded. How would you do this?

I've looked at the post showing how to generate a progress bar, which I still don't quite understand the code, but I couldn't get it to work with pull. I've tried using progress with gitpython, but again, I couldn't get it to work with pull. And I've tried piping stdout and stderr to the textbrowser, but it would just hang not feeding any text.

Test code:

```
class upd(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(upd, self).__init__(parent)
        uic.loadUi(os.path.join("C:\\", "testd.ui"))
    
    def poptext(self, p):
        sel = selectors.DefaultSelector()
        sel.register(p.stdout, selectors.EVENT_READ)
        sel.register(p.stderr, selectors.EVENT_READ)

        while True:
            for key, _ in sel.select():
                data = key.fileobj.read().decode()
                if not data:
                    break
                if key.fileobj is p.stdout:
                    self.textBrowser.insertPlainText(data + "\n")
                else:
                    self.textBrowser.insertPlainText(data + "\n")
        self.textBrowser.insertPlainText("Done.")

def test():
    url = "https://github.com/e4862/test.git"
    path = "C:\\test\\"
    clone_repo(url, path)

# Function to clone repo from git
def clone_repo(repo_url, path):
    args = []
    args.append("git")
    args.append("clone")
    args.append("--progress")
    args.append(repo_url)
    args.append(path)

    p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE, shell = True, creationflags = subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)

    testupd = upd()
    testupd.poptext(p)
    testupd.exec()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    test()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: Please don't create new questions that are fundamentally identical to [those you deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68585407/feed-gitprogress-to-qtextbrowser). Instead, edit those posts and add comments to them (if you are the author of the question, you *can* comment!).

Comment: @musicamante Yeah...It also says "closed" because it found a similar post, so I have no idea if it disables viewing of the post and I still need help.

Comment: @e4862 In the duplicate of the post you just have to change to: `w.run("git clone --progress https://github.com/e4862/test.git C:\\test\\")`

Comment: @eyllanesc I don't understand what you're referring to.

Comment: @e4862 In the code of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51829328/6622587) the duplicate only changes `w.run("ping 8.8.8.8 -c 100")` for what I already pointed out to you

Comment: @eyllanesc I'm trying to queue new tasks for the window after the process finishes, but I can't get the finished signal to go to the function I have it set to call when the signal connects.

Comment: @e4862 That is another task that that code does not implement but in another post I already implemented it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53461496/trying-to-get-qprocess-to-work-with-a-queue/53463275#53463275. I recommend you do a preliminary investigation, here I will only answer the question of the duplicate and other comments (like the previous one) I will ignore them. Here we solve specific problems and we do not help to implement projects since that would be too much.

Comment: @eyllanesc I'm asking a question about a specific problem... self.process.finished.connect(self.onFinished) self.onFinished is not being called, so I'm trying to see why that might be the case.

Comment: @e4862 The goal of your current post is: *Continuously redirect Git progress to QTextBrowser*, and that has nothing to do with your new question